# Cut an object from another object and create faces

Tags: modifiers, faces

I'm looking to create an object using the boolean modifier method (`add modifier` -> `boolean` -> `difference`). The problem is that the newly created object doesn't have faces as shown below. How to cut it by creating its sides/faces?

[image]

Comment: switch normals and make sure it is one full seamless mesh with no holes

Comment: I'm new to Blender, not sure what you mean. How to switch normals?

Comment: Ok, I've found it! It didn't work at the first time as the new object flat side was inside the cutting one.